# Código php no inserta datos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

El siguiente código php no funciona y no sé a que es debido. $lista es un array de Strings al igual que $adicional. Los dos arrays tienen la misma longitud y quiero que dados los arrays $lista y $adicional, todos sus valores se inserten en la base de datos. También he realizado la conexión a la base de datos y la he guardado en la variable $conn. A simple vista no me muestra ningún error, pero no se inserta nada en la base de datos. Gracias.

```php
    include_once 'db_conexion.php';

$lista = $_POST['list'];
$adicional = $_POST['aditional_info'];

try {

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($lista); $i++) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO links (enlace, adicional) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $lista[$i], $adicional[$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    $resultado = array(
        'respuesta' => 'exito'
    );

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

    $resultado = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error'
    );

}

die(json_encode($resultado));
```

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$stmt->error` justo después de `$stmt->execute()`.

Comment: y cual es el contenido de `$lista` y `$adicional`

Comment: Vale, ya lo he solucionado, me he dado cuenta del error gracias a tu aportación, resulta que el formato del string no lo soporta ya que es un emoticono. ¿Habría alguna manera de que no diera el error?. (me sale que el emoticono es '\xF0\x9F\x8F\xB4\xF3\xA0...' ). Muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba anteponiendo el conjunto de caracteres a la cadena: `_ucs2'\xF0\x9F'`

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias por la aportación!!